# Postgres - Expanding sparse data

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
 x | y | f
 =========
 0 | 1  | 3.4
 1 | 2  | 3.5
```

Only certain x and y values exist in the table.  PK is x,y.

I'd like to expand it, so that *all* x and y values exist. For any already existing value, keep f.  For new rows, set f = 0.  So, in the above, we'd add `(0,0,0.0), (1,0,0.0), (1,1,0.0)` etc.

I think this can be done with some type of JOIN to `generate_range`, but I'm not sure how to cause it to only do so for cases where the record is absent from the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO t (x, y, f)
SELECT a.x, b.y, 0.0
FROM
  generate_series(0, 1000000) a(x)
  CROSS JOIN generate_series(0, 1000000) b(y)
  LEFT JOIN t ON
    t.x = a.x AND t.y = b.y
  WHERE t.x IS NULL
```